# MySQL UNION ALL Multiple usage optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, dynamic, union

I am having issues in MySQL query optimization.
Situation is like below.
There are over 200000 rows with multi columns in a SQL table.
And I am making filter options in frontend for these data.
For instance, two columns "Year" and "Make".
And there are many values like "2021", 2022, 2019, 2010 in Year columns, while "Ford", "Chevrolet" and so on in Make.
Example Link:
https://www.autobidmaster.com/en/carfinder-online-auto-auctions/?make=Chevrolet

These values are not unique in each columns. and
I am gonna make filter options(unique value :  it's count in each column) based on unique values for these two columns.
I thought I can use data grouped by unique values in each and merge them using UNION ALL in single query.
For instance: for two columns  Year and Make

```
$sql1 = "
           (SELECT 'Make' as filter_option_name ,Make as filter_options_key_name, COUNT(*) as filter_option_count
           FROM dbcopart.wprdb_copartdata ". $where_str ."
           GROUP BY filter_options_key_name
           ORDER BY filter_options_key_name)
           UNION ALL 
           (SELECT 'Year' as filter_option_name ,Year as filter_options_key_name, COUNT(*) as filter_option_count
           FROM dbcopart.wprdb_copartdata  ". $where_str ."
           GROUP BY filter_options_key_name
           ORDER BY filter_options_key_name) "
```

WIth two columns, it was okay. worked properly.
But there are another columns: over 20 columns to be used as filter option.
20 time UNION ALL for over 200000 rows was slow.
How can I improve my SQL query?
I think there should be another effective way instead of my stupid 'multiple UNION ALL'.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Question: As people are adding filters for "Year" and "Make" and "Colour" and whatnot, will the counts be expected to change? If you have 50,000 red cars in the database, but I choose Lamborghini as the Make, it would not make sense to show 50,000 anymore. Does your website go back to the database after every filter option is selected to further refine the number of matches?

Comment: Hello Sorry for late, yes it should be refined again. This is why I am getting stress. since if we don't need to refine match count , I can save all filter options in another table as static and use it later.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UNION ALL` is probably optimal for gathering all 20 sets of counts at one time.  But consider running that once an hour and storing it into another table -- then use fetch from that table.  (The data will be a little stale, but perhaps good enough for the use case.)

Yes, once they picked 'Lamborghini', you will have to go back to the table to get the revised values for all the counts (minus `make`).  If there is an index *starting with* `make`, then this second big UNION will be faster than the first.

Two layers might be worth caching; more than that will take a lot of space for minimal benefit.

Consider keeping the entire dataset in memory and using app code to do the necessary counts; it will probably be faster than using SQL.  (But a lot more code.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Could you explain how to make the index starting with make again? And regarding of memory usage, in fact I am putting dataset from CSV already existed to database every 15 minutes, based on cron job. I maybe use CSV itself instead of Database?

Comment: @JansenLee - Example: `ALTER TABLE wprdb_copartdata ADD INDEX(make, year)`.  CSV has no useful indexing; you are probably better off with a database.  Start a new question about the 15-minute cron job; multiple red flags come up.